# elastic search order by function result (sqrt)

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, sqrt

I have the following data saved in elastic

```json
{
   "data" : {
       "c1" : -0.343404934,
       "c2" : -0.1234212345,
       "c3" : 0.003404934
   }
}
```

I need to sort by square root with the summery of power in each field.
In sql I would write it:

```sql
SELECT c1,c2,c3 from table
ORDER BY sqrt( 
     power(c1 - external_param_c1, 2) + power(c2 - external_param_c2, 2) + power(c2 - external_param_c3, 2) 
)
```

How can I translate it to elastic?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need a [scripted sort](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sort-search-results.html#_script_based_sorting) utilizing the [`Math` painless library](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/current/painless-api-reference-shared-java-lang.html#painless-api-reference-shared-Math):

```
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "_script": {
        "type": "number",
        "order": "desc",
        "script": {
          "source": "Math.sqrt(Math.pow(doc['data.c1'].value - params.external_param_c1, 2) + Math.pow(doc['data.c2'].value - params.external_param_c2, 2) + Math.pow(doc['data.c3'].value - params.external_param_c3, 2))",
          "params": {
            "external_param_c1": 1,
            "external_param_c2": 2,
            "external_param_c3": 3
          }
        }
      }
      
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Appreciated.  Thanks